# XSD to Excel to XML

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I have an XSD file that I would like to use to create an Excel template for completion by my clients. Once I have filled out the fields they need, I would like to convert this Excel file to an XML file. I keep trying to move the XSD file into Excel to get it to map correctly.

However, when I go to save the file as an XML file, I get the error that the maps are not exportable. My XSD file has a number of sections and many fields in the section that I am using that are listed as "necessary".

- I am wondering if it would be possible to simplify the XSD to make it exportable to XML?
- Or if someone could take a look at my XSD file and help me figure out how to map?

If someone wanted to do it with me watching, I would be interested in hiring you for an hour's work...
My Excel skills are strong, but I am just starting on learning to code.
Thanks for any input someone may have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: And where is this xsd to look at?

Comment: Hi Parfait, Thank you for looking at my question. Here is a link to the XSD document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2fop6b0av6xca6/ACES_3_2_rev5_20160331.xsd?dl=0